# application pool user identity invalid some of the build runs

Tags: tfs, iis-6, application-pool, was

On our TFS build server, we're getting the following error *most builds* (so not ALL builds, sometimes the build runs perfectly!)

"The identity of application pool application_pool_name is invalid. The user name or password that is specified for the identity may be incorrect, or the user may not have batch logon rights. If the identity is not corrected, the application pool will be disabled when the application pool receives its first request.  If batch logon rights are causing the problem, the identity in the IIS configuration store must be changed after rights have been granted before Windows Process Activation Service (WAS) can retry the logon. If the identity remains invalid after the first request for the application pool is processed, the application pool will be disabled. The data field contains the error number."

Since it runs some builds, we know the identity is in fact not invalid and that it's not a code problem. Does anybody know if there are any other cases where you can get this specific error? We've had this problem for several months now...

EDIT: We've also found out it started after MS updates KB4015547 and KB4015550, but uninstalling them didn't help. Re-entering the user or using another user didn't work either.

Comment: Did you got any related error info in Event View?

Comment: No, only this one, and afterwards comes an error: "Application pool application_pool_name has been disabled. Windows Process Activation Service (WAS) encountered a failure when it started a worker process to serve the application pool."
But the reason is the error mentioned above.

We've also found out it started after MS updates (KB4015547 and KB4015550), but uninstalling it didn't help. We've also tried re-entering the user and using anothe user.

Answer (score 0):

> The identity of all application pools should **be set to the
>   correspondingservice account that you specified when you installed
>   Team Foundation Server** (TFSService).

Change the identity and then try to stop and restart the application pool. For this, open **Internet Information Services (IIS) Manager**, expand the local computer and open **Application Pools**. Open the navigation menu and choose **Stop** or **Start**.

Restart the application pool so that Windows Process Activation Service (WAS) can determine the correct state of the protocol.

If above is still not working, you could also try  reset the IIS entirely. More ways you could take a look at this thread: [An application pool is not configured correctly](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee248591(v=vs.100).aspx)

Comment: We've already tried this. Right now we have a(n ugly) workaround: our deployment script does an IISreset every time a new build starts, which results in that build running perfectly with the current configuration. (If we only do it once manually, it'll just break down during one of the following deployments again, and not necessarily the first) However, this means we can't reach TFS for a moment every time we deploy...